# Cannot pass entire for loop to email body in Python

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

First let me state that I am not a developer and have no formal training. I have a little experience with Python and have written scripts for telecom reporting. I'm working on a script that queries a database to determine the number of times a keypad was pressed. For example, key 1 was pressed 100 times, key 2 was pressed 300 times and so forth. I've been able to successfully retrieve the data and when I use the print function it works fine. However, when I attempt to take that same data and get it into the body of an email, it only seems to show the second index and not the first. Can someone help me understand why this happens and suggest how to correct? My for loop is indented, my email code is not. I've tried changing indenting and end up with two incorrect emails instead of one.

```
for row in data:
    rowtolist = [elem for elem in row]
    buttonkey = rowtolist[0]
    timespressed = rowtolist[1]
    data1 = 'Button {} was pressed {} times'.format(buttonkey,timespressed)
    print(data1)
```

Output is:

```
Button 1 was pressed 710 times
Button 2 was pressed 1353 times
```

but when I attempt to take this data and add it to an email with this:

```
SERVER = "smtp.server"
FROM = "mysmtpserver"
TO = ["testemailaddress"]

SUBJECT = "Cisco Unity Report"
TEXT = data

message = """From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\

%s\r\n

""" %(FROM, ",".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
cursor.close()
```

I get this in my email body :

```
Button 2 was pressed 1353 times
```

I'd like to know why I cannot get the same info as if I am using the print function.

Comment: You want to send 2 separate emails, with these 2 messages, or just 1 with both?

Comment: Just one email for now. Possible additional recipients later. But one email with Button 1 was pressed 710 times
Button 2 was pressed 1353 times in the message body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume `data` and `data1` are same.

You need to store the result of each iteration as follows,

```
results = list()
for row in data:
    rowtolist = [elem for elem in row]
    buttonkey = rowtolist[0]
    timespressed = rowtolist[1]
    data = f'Button {buttonkey} was pressed {timespressed} times'
    results.append(data)
```

Then you can attach the result to the mail body as follows,

```
TEXT = "\n".join(results)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I really appreciate your help Manoj. I marked the reply as useful but since I am a new user it is not displayed.